# Expression for counting features that intersect other layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, expression, count

I'm working with QGIS 3.16 Hannover.

I've got a single polygon layer `National Park` and another layer with a 1x1 km grid `UTM`. In the print composer, I want to include in the legend the number of `UTM` grid squares that intersect the `National Park` (**all** features of `UTM` with **all** features of `National Park`, so I get **one** number as result). I've built the following code, but it returns 0.

```
aggregate(
          layer:='UTM', 
          aggregate:='count', 
          expression:='COD1X1', 
          filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry('National Park') 
                            ) 
          )
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the count of **all** `UTM`-features that intersect with **the current** `National Park` feature:

```
aggregate(
          layer:='UTM', 
          aggregate:='count', 
          expression:='COD1X1', 
          filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)) 
)
```

To count **all** `UTM`-Features that intersect with **all** `National Park` features:

```
aggregate(
          layer:='UTM', 
          aggregate:='count', 
          expression:='COD1X1', 
          filter:=intersects($geometry,aggregate('National Park','collect',$geometry)) 
)
```